# definition of differentiation, continuity in multivariables.

Tags: real-analysis

I am misunderstanding the diff/continuity definitions in multivariable.

If you take a look here [How to show differentiability implies continuity for functions between Euclidean spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172666/how-to-show-differentiability-implies-continuity-for-functions-between-euclidean)

the original post states that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(a+h) - f(a) - \lambda(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0$$

in my definitions I have that $$\lim_{\|h\| \to 0} \frac{\|f(a+h) - f(a) - \lambda(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0$$

which one would be correct? for instance to say a function is continuous at a point $a$ would we say that $$\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)$$ or $$\lim_{\|h\| \to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)$$?

Comment: It's the same. $h \to b$ is by definition the same as $\lVert h - b\rVert \to 0$. Take $b = 0$ for this special case.

Answer (score 1):

The two are equivalent, I believe. The only way for the norm of $h$ to go to zero is for $h$ to go to zero.

Comment: Just to be really pedantic: As @DanielFischer stated in a comment, it's not that one convergence *implies* the other one by some theorem, it's that this is the *definition* of convergence in a metric space. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Open_and_closed_sets.2C_topology_and_convergence): "A sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space M is said to converge to the limit $x \in M$ iff for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N$." (Where $d(x_n,x)=\lVert x_n-x\rVert$ in spaces with a metric induced by a norm.)